# Use imagemagick to output rotated text as png

Tags: imagemagick

I need to output a png image that has as content a text label rotated 90 degrees, this is the code I'm trying with

```
 convert 
 -size 50X100 
 -draw 'font Baskerville font-size 24  
       translate 10,10 rotate 90 text 0,0 
       'True'' true.png
```

unfortunately this gives me the following error messages

```
convert: unable to open image 'True': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3496.

convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562.

convert: no images defined `true.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3282.
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is incorrect. You should have multiple commands instead of having everything in the *draw*.

```
convert -size 50X100 -font Baskerville font-size 24 -translate 10,10 -rotate 90 -draw "text 0,0 \"True\"" true.png
```

Cheers!

Comment: trying convert -size 50X100 -font Baskerville font-size 24 -translate 10,10 -rotate 90 -draw "text 0,0 \"True\"" true.png getting
convert: unable to open image 'font-size': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3496.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562.
convert: unable to open image '24': actually I guess it was missing the - in front of font-size etc.